# How to get order id in filter 'woocommerce_email_attachments'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to attach the invoice as PDF to the WooCommerce Mail. Works great with static PDFs (like terms and conditions), but I need the option to work with variable PDF-Files (like invoices).

I use this filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);
```

and this function:

```
function attach_pdf_to_email ( $attachments, $status , $object ) {

$pdf_path = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/terms.pdf";
$attachments[] = $pdf_path;

return $attachments;

}
```

Works perfectly. Now I want to change $pdf_path to this:

```
$pdf_path = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/terms" . $order_id . ".pdf";
```

But I am not able to get the $order_id.

I tried:

```
global $order;

// First try
$order_id = $order->id;

// Second try
$order_id = $order->get_id();

// Third and fourth try (like above)
global $post;
```

The problem is, that the filter sends neither the order, nor the order id. Is there any way or idea, how I can achieve that?

Comment: print this `$object ` object then you will get order id.

Comment: I cannot print $object, because the filter is only adding the files to the WooCommerce Mails.

Answer (score 2):

you can get order id from `$object`.
try below code, i have tried your code and edited it to get order id

```
function attach_pdf_to_email($attachments, $status, $object) {
    $order_id = method_exists($object, 'get_id') ? $object->get_id() : $object->id;

    $pdf_path = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/terms" . $order_id . ".pdf";
//  $pdf_path = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/terms.pdf";

    $attachments[] = $pdf_path;

    return $attachments;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Can u try to print it and check if you are getting order id or not?

Comment: Sorry. I am an idiot. I made a mistake, your code works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);

function attach_agb_to_email ( $attachments, $status , $order ) {

    if ( empty( $order ) ) {
        return $attachments;
    }

    $order_id = $order->id;
    $pdf_path = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/terms" . $order_id . ".pdf";

    $attachments[] = $pdf_path;

    return $attachments;

}
```

Comment: Sorry. I am an idiot. I made a mistake, your code works perfectly as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'wh_attach_document_into_email', 10, 3 );
    function wh_attach_document_into_email ( $attachments, $email_id, $object ){
        $order_id = $object->order->get_order_number();
        //`enter code here`
        return $attachments;
    }
```

Tested Woo > 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

you have order object and from this object you can get order id i tried its working

```
function af_ips_add_attachments($attachments, $email_id, $order, $email ){
    $af_e = $order->get_id();
    update_option('af_ips_emails',$af_e );
    $af_attachkment = WP_CONTENT_DIR .'\uploads\af-invoices/af- Invoice.pdf';
    $email_ids = array( 'customer_on_hold_order', 'customer_processing_order' );
    if ( in_array ( $email_id, $email_ids ) ) {
        $attachments[] = $af_attachkment;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```